# SQL/PHP code - Getting the sum of each months values

Tags: php, sql, database

These is a database which is formatted like this.

```
Date         Count
'2001-03-04'   4
'2001-03-05'   5
'2001-03-06'   4
'2001-03-08'   1
'2001-03-09'   3
```

This database goes on for 15 years or so.
I need to display a rolling 12 month graph displaying counts and month.
How would I find the sum of each month in a 12 month period.

iv tried that

```
$sql_months = "SELECT date(D.`created`) 'Date', count(*) 'Count' 
FROM  mytable
group by date(D.`created`)
where D.`created` >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())";
$result_months = $conn->query($sql_months);
```

How would I achieve this with php or sql code.

month  count
   8      12
   11      06

etc for each month, 12 months backward from the current month.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the results that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by month, not by date, and sum the counts rather than just counting them. And the `WHERE` clause goes before `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT YEAR(created) AS year, MONTH(created) AS month, SUM(count) AS count
FROM mytable
WHERE created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY year, month
```

You need to group by both year and month, otherwise you'll combine the values from the current month a year ago with this month.